# Operation synchronisation challenge in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

I have 3 operations: `A`, `B`, `C`.

- `A`, `B` can be processed concurrently
- if `C` runs, `A` and `B` should wait
- if `A` or `B` runs `C` should wait

I would solve it with a dispatch group and a semaphore:

```
public var dgLoadMain = dispatch_group_create()
public var semaLoadMain = dispatch_semaphore_create(1)
```

`A`, `B` would look like this:

```
dispatch_group_enter(dgLoadMain)
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaLoadMain, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaLoadMain) //maybe odd, but right after wait, it signals, it just check wether C is in critical section, if not, release semaphore, and let other B or A continue too
//..
dispatch_group_leave(dgLoadMain)
```

`C` would look like this:

```
dispatch_group_wait(dgLoadMain, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaLoadMain, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
//..
dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaLoadMain)
```

Do you think it is OK?

Comment: The program always starts to process A and B at the same time?

Comment: `A`, `B`, `C`  are arbitrary operations / chunks of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatch_barrier_async` is more sophisticated. Take a look at this code. It's Objective-C but the same concept absolutely works well on Swift.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void A()
{
    NSLog(@"A begin");
    sleep(1);
    NSLog(@"A end");
}

void B()
{
    NSLog(@"B begin");
    sleep(1);
    NSLog(@"B end");
}

void C()
{
    NSLog(@"C begin");
    sleep(1);
    NSLog(@"C end");
}

int main()
{
    dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_queue_create("ABC", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

    dispatch_queue_t qA = dispatch_queue_create("A", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_set_target_queue(qA, q);

    dispatch_queue_t qB = dispatch_queue_create("B", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_set_target_queue(qB, q);

    dispatch_barrier_async(q, ^{C();});
    dispatch_async(qA, ^{A();});
    dispatch_async(qA, ^{A();});
    dispatch_async(qB, ^{B();});
    dispatch_barrier_async(q, ^{C();});
    dispatch_async(qB, ^{B();});
    dispatch_barrier_async(q, ^{C();});
    dispatch_async(qA, ^{A();});

    dispatch_main();
    return 0;
}
```

The result.

```
C begin
C end
A begin
B begin
A end
B end
B begin
A begin
B end
A end
A begin
A end
C begin
C end
C begin
C end
```

Comment: nice, one question, if `C` looks like `mainMOC.performBlockAndWait({ .. })` and `A` or `B` is like `temporaryContext.performBlockAndWait({ .. })` with parent to `mainMOC` then how can I wrap `C` into a barrier?

Comment: Those code would work from dispatch_async and dispatch_barrier_async, but those performBlockAndWait are really needed? Anyway, I recommend you ask a new question about what you really want to do.

Comment: I rephrased my question, could you check it, I am curious about your opinion? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232431/how-to-prevent-temporarycontext-run-concurrently-with-migratepersistentstore

Answer (score 0):

Your solution probably works but reasoning about its correctness was painful. I came up with what I thought was a cleaner solution. It uses 2 semaphores. It basically combines down task A and task B and looks at them as one task. And then it uses the timeout property to check if either task A or task B was finished previously and signals to the first semaphore accordingly. Here's the code:

```
let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
let ABSema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    print("A")
    if !Bool(dispatch_semaphore_wait(ABSema, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW))
    {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(ABSema)
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }

})
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    print("B")
    if !Bool(dispatch_semaphore_wait(ABSema, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW))
    {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(ABSema)
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }
})


dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    print("C")
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
})
```

Comment: it is challenge because 3 operations exist, not 2, - even if `A`, `B` behaves in the same way, these are two different chunk of code - and I want to know is it any drawback using my code, so waiting for reasoning

Comment: Yes, I know its 3 operations thus, the print A, print B and print C. The way this works is it locks around A and B together and only notifies C after both A and B are finished using the ABSema as a synchronization technique. Thus, if A or B starts C won't start till both of them are done as requested. And if C starts A and B won't start till C finishes. The print just represents the actual task you need to put in there.